Can the react-native IOS podfile using use_flipper and use_framework at the same time?
My application would build failed after I add the custom framework. The custom framework would need to using the iOSOTARTK and iOSDFULibrary framework
however, when I updated the podfile, run the pod install, it would return the following error
 Library not loaded: @rpath/ZIPFoundation.framework/ZIPFoundation

Also, I have a custom framework would saving in  [project] > [framework] > [XXX.framework]
Would any method for the react-native allow the xcode cocoapods framework and the flipper framework at the same time ?
podfile
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'XXXXXX' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )


  #target 'XXXXXX' do
  #  inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  #end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)

  # Add these lines for Xcode 14 builds
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
    end
  # End of added lines
  end

  # react-native-permissions permission handlers
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"

  pod 'AZSClient'
  pod 'iOSOTARTK'
  pod 'iOSDFULibrary'
  pod 'ZIPFoundation'
  pod 'Zip', '~> 2.1'

end

